# How to implement xml based webservices in cake php 3

Tags: xml, web-services, crud, cakephp-3.0

we have implemented friendsofcake CRUD plugin in our cakephp 3 project and exposed the data successfully as web services in JSON format. But we are not able to post/add the data using XML format. We were able to get the data in xml format successfully in GET request by using the .xml extension in the url. We have include the RequestHandler component and added 'json' and 'xml' in the route.Abd also used the cotenttype and accept headers as 'application/xml'.

Can you help us what the request format should be for the model to successfully save the data in the database by POST method in XML format.

Comment: How are you posting the data? CakePHP is able to transform an XML document into an array when it is posted using the `Content-type:application/xml` header

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using both 'Accept' and 'Content-Type' headers with 'application/xml'. But I am looking for example XML bodies I can use, similar to the JSON bodies for a POST or PUT request.To get the student model when I use http://myurl.com/myproject/student.xml, I get the response successfully as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<success>1</success>
<data>
  <id>1</id>
  <memberid>AB10007</memberid>
  <name>Kishore</name>
  <password>kishore</password>
  <standard>X</standard>
  <section>A</section>
  <branch_id>1</branch_id>
</data>
</response>.